# Creating custom CLI tools for a Meteor app

Tags: meteor, command-line-interface

I'm working on a Meteor app (a port from a PHP project) and I need to be able to run commands on my app from the server for various operations like clearing caches, aggregating data, etc.  These commands need to be run from shell scripts and crontab.  I've seen other people ask this question and apparently there's no official way to do it yet.

I read a suggestion of using Meteor methods and just calling them from the client's JS console with a password.  This doesn't solve my problem of running them from the CLI, but it did give me an idea:

Would it be possible to use a headless browser (like PhantomJS) to connect to my app and execute Meteor.call() to simulate a CLI tool with arguments passed to the method?  If possible, does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **EDIT**: Updated to use Iron Router, the successor to Meteor Router.

There's no need for a headless browser or anything complicated. Use [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/) to install [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) and define a server-side route:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('clearCache', {
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
      // Your cache-clearing code goes here.
    }
  });
});
```

Then have your cronjob trigger an HTTP GET request to that URI:

```
curl http://yoursite.com/clearCache
```

When the Meteor server receives the GET request, the router will execute your code.

For a little bit of security, add a check for a password:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('clearCache', {
    path: '/clearCache/:password',
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
      if (this.params.password == '2d1QZuK3R3a7fe46FX8huj517juvzciem73') {
        // Your cache-clearing code goes here.
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And have your cronjob add that password to the URI:

```
curl http://yoursite.com/clearCache/2d1QZuK3R3a7fe46FX8huj517juvzciem73
```

> **Original Post**:

There's no need for a headless browser or anything complicated. Use [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/) to install [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) and define a server-side route:

```
Meteor.Router.add('/clearCache', function() {
  // Your cache-clearing code goes here.
});
```

Then have your cronjob trigger an HTTP GET request to that URI:

```
curl http://yoursite.com/clearCache
```

When the Meteor server receives the GET request, the router will execute your code.

For a little bit of security, add a check for a password:

```
Meteor.Router.add('/clearCache/:password', function(password) {
  if (password == '2d1QZuK3R3a7fe46FX8huj517juvzciem73') {
    // Your cache-clearing code goes here.
  }
});
```

And have your cronjob add that password to the URI:

```
curl http://yoursite.com/clearCache/2d1QZuK3R3a7fe46FX8huj517juvzciem73
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Meteor app, which does exactly that:

http://meteor-shell.meteor.com/

Why do you need a CLI tool when you could just store some scripts on the server and execute them from an admin interface in your Meteor app?

Comment: The reason we need CLI tools is because we need to script things like clearing caches, aggregating data, etc... some of which need to be executed as cron jobs.  That's difficult to do from a browser.

Comment: This appears to be the opposite of what I need.  This allows you to run shell commands in a browser (which I don't need) but does not allow me to interact with my app from the linux shell (what I really need)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same question yesterday. Found this Package, but have not yet tried it
https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mcli

> **Overview**
>
> A meteor package and command line tools for creating and running
>   command line / cli programs with meteor.
>
> **Incentive**
>
> To be able to reuse the same code of your meteor app in your command
>   line programs, instead of having to create a separate node / npm code
>   base with lot's of code duplicated from your meteor app.